# Using virtual environment folder to run open source code on pycharm

Tags: python, dependencies, pycharm, open-source

I am new to source codes and how to run them. I am also new to python. I would like to know how I can use a virtual environment folder I installed all of my dependencies on through command prompt to run my source code.

I have a source code for a program called PrintRun I got from github and it required 7 dependencies. 
Here is the link: https://github.com/kliment/Printrun 
Using the command prompt window, I made a folder for virtualenv and then installed the dependencies within it. Afterwards I imported the source code folder into pycharm. The code doesn't run. What am I suppose to do with the folder? IS there something I am missing here?

Here is the error message I am getting from pycharm when I try running the pronterface file.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/lolo/Downloads/scarf/Printrun-printrun-2.0.0rc5/printrun/pronterface.py", line 31, in

```
from . import pronsole
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'pronsole' from '**main**' (C:/Users/lolo/Downloads/scarf/Printrun-printrun-2.0.0rc5/printrun/pronterface.py)

Process finished with exit code 1

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project in pycharm you can choose existing files and virtual environments. I suggest reading the [official pycharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/documentation/).

Also, please include code and error messages when asking questions!